# (optimization help) Finding ways to post 3 letters in 5 postboxes in python

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a mathematical problem that i need to solve using python. (Read full qn pls,)

Problem :-

> Find all ways to post 3 letters in 5 postboxes assuming all letters and postboxes are distinct.

I tried to solve it on paper for 2 hours but my brain got roasted, so i decided to do it via python

I tried using itertools product but no success.

Then i tried using nested for loops and got this :-

```py
count = 0

a,b,c,d,e = [],[],[],[],[]

for A in range(1,6):
    for B in range(1,6):
        for C in range(1,6):
            
            a.clear()
            b.clear()
            c.clear()
            d.clear()
            e.clear()
            
            if A == 1:
                a.append(A)
            elif A == 2:
                b.append(A)
            elif A == 3:
                c.append(A)
            elif A == 4:
                d.append(A)
            elif A == 5:
                e.append(A)

            if B == 1:
                a.append(B)
            elif B == 2:
                b.append(B)
            elif B == 3:
                c.append(B)
            elif B == 4:
                d.append(B)
            elif B == 5:
                e.append(B)

            if C == 1:
                a.append(C)
            elif C == 2:
                b.append(C)
            elif C == 3:
                c.append(C)
            elif C == 4:
                d.append(C)
            elif C == 5:
                e.append(C)
            
            print(f'{str(a).ljust(12)} {str(b).ljust(12)} {str(c).ljust(12)} {str(d).ljust(12)} {str(e).ljust(12)}')
            count += 1

print('\nCount :',count)
```

Output :-

```
[1, 1, 1]    []           []           []           []
[1, 1]       [2]          []           []           []
[1, 1]       []           [3]          []           []
[1, 1]       []           []           [4]          []
[1, 1]       []           []           []           [5]
[1, 1]       [2]          []           []           []
[1]          [2, 2]       []           []           []
[1]          [2]          [3]          []           []
[1]          [2]          []           [4]          []
[1]          [2]          []           []           [5]
[1, 1]       []           [3]          []           []
[1]          [2]          [3]          []           []
[1]          []           [3, 3]       []           []
[1]          []           [3]          [4]          []
[1]          []           [3]          []           [5]
[1, 1]       []           []           [4]          []
[1]          [2]          []           [4]          []
[1]          []           [3]          [4]          []
[1]          []           []           [4, 4]       []
[1]          []           []           [4]          [5]
[1, 1]       []           []           []           [5]
[1]          [2]          []           []           [5]
[1]          []           [3]          []           [5]
[1]          []           []           [4]          [5]
[1]          []           []           []           [5, 5]
[1, 1]       [2]          []           []           []
[1]          [2, 2]       []           []           []
[1]          [2]          [3]          []           []
[1]          [2]          []           [4]          []
[1]          [2]          []           []           [5]
[1]          [2, 2]       []           []           []
[]           [2, 2, 2]    []           []           []
[]           [2, 2]       [3]          []           []
[]           [2, 2]       []           [4]          []
[]           [2, 2]       []           []           [5]
[1]          [2]          [3]          []           []
[]           [2, 2]       [3]          []           []
[]           [2]          [3, 3]       []           []
[]           [2]          [3]          [4]          []
[]           [2]          [3]          []           [5]
[1]          [2]          []           [4]          []
[]           [2, 2]       []           [4]          []
[]           [2]          [3]          [4]          []
[]           [2]          []           [4, 4]       []
[]           [2]          []           [4]          [5]
[1]          [2]          []           []           [5]
[]           [2, 2]       []           []           [5]
[]           [2]          [3]          []           [5]
[]           [2]          []           [4]          [5]
[]           [2]          []           []           [5, 5]
[1, 1]       []           [3]          []           []
[1]          [2]          [3]          []           []
[1]          []           [3, 3]       []           []
[1]          []           [3]          [4]          []
[1]          []           [3]          []           [5]
[1]          [2]          [3]          []           []
[]           [2, 2]       [3]          []           []
[]           [2]          [3, 3]       []           []
[]           [2]          [3]          [4]          []
[]           [2]          [3]          []           [5]
[1]          []           [3, 3]       []           []
[]           [2]          [3, 3]       []           []
[]           []           [3, 3, 3]    []           []
[]           []           [3, 3]       [4]          []
[]           []           [3, 3]       []           [5]
[1]          []           [3]          [4]          []
[]           [2]          [3]          [4]          []
[]           []           [3, 3]       [4]          []
[]           []           [3]          [4, 4]       []
[]           []           [3]          [4]          [5]
[1]          []           [3]          []           [5]
[]           [2]          [3]          []           [5]
[]           []           [3, 3]       []           [5]
[]           []           [3]          [4]          [5]
[]           []           [3]          []           [5, 5]
[1, 1]       []           []           [4]          []
[1]          [2]          []           [4]          []
[1]          []           [3]          [4]          []
[1]          []           []           [4, 4]       []
[1]          []           []           [4]          [5]
[1]          [2]          []           [4]          []
[]           [2, 2]       []           [4]          []
[]           [2]          [3]          [4]          []
[]           [2]          []           [4, 4]       []
[]           [2]          []           [4]          [5]
[1]          []           [3]          [4]          []
[]           [2]          [3]          [4]          []
[]           []           [3, 3]       [4]          []
[]           []           [3]          [4, 4]       []
[]           []           [3]          [4]          [5]
[1]          []           []           [4, 4]       []
[]           [2]          []           [4, 4]       []
[]           []           [3]          [4, 4]       []
[]           []           []           [4, 4, 4]    []
[]           []           []           [4, 4]       [5]
[1]          []           []           [4]          [5]
[]           [2]          []           [4]          [5]
[]           []           [3]          [4]          [5]
[]           []           []           [4, 4]       [5]
[]           []           []           [4]          [5, 5]
[1, 1]       []           []           []           [5]
[1]          [2]          []           []           [5]
[1]          []           [3]          []           [5]
[1]          []           []           [4]          [5]
[1]          []           []           []           [5, 5]
[1]          [2]          []           []           [5]
[]           [2, 2]       []           []           [5]
[]           [2]          [3]          []           [5]
[]           [2]          []           [4]          [5]
[]           [2]          []           []           [5, 5]
[1]          []           [3]          []           [5]
[]           [2]          [3]          []           [5]
[]           []           [3, 3]       []           [5]
[]           []           [3]          [4]          [5]
[]           []           [3]          []           [5, 5]
[1]          []           []           [4]          [5]
[]           [2]          []           [4]          [5]
[]           []           [3]          [4]          [5]
[]           []           []           [4, 4]       [5]
[]           []           []           [4]          [5, 5]
[1]          []           []           []           [5, 5]
[]           [2]          []           []           [5, 5]
[]           []           [3]          []           [5, 5]
[]           []           []           [4]          [5, 5]
[]           []           []           []           [5, 5, 5]

Count : 125
```

**It Works!**

**But the code seems to long. Is there any technique to simplify the code ? (Especially the if-elif part)**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your code, you can simplify like this:

```py
count = 0
for A in range(1,6):
    for B in range(1,6):
        for C in range(1,6):
            a,b,c,d,e = [],[],[],[],[]
            data = [a,b,c,d,e]
            for n in [A,B,C]:
                data[n-1].append(n)
            print(f'{str(a).ljust(12)} {str(b).ljust(12)} {str(c).ljust(12)} {str(d).ljust(12)} {str(e).ljust(12)}')
            count += 1
print('\nCount :',count)
```

Comment: But can you explain how is it even working ?

Comment: your values ```1,2,3,4,5``` correspond to the lists ```a,b,c,d,e``` , when I put the lists into   the list ```data```, ```a,b,c,d,e``` 's position in ```data``` are ```0,1,2,3,4```, are just ```value-1```